# How to cancel UItouchevent for UIlabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

I do not want touchesBegan event should not fire when user taps on UILabel.
How do i achive it?.
any help will be appreicated.thanks in advance.

Comment: If the solutions below don't work, then your question isn't clear.  What, exactly, are you trying to do?  What have you tried to date?  Show us the associated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable user intaractions for your label

```
[yourLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: after i make userInteractionEnabled:YES i can catch UIlabel inside UITouchEvent..

Answer (score 0):

Disable userInteraction on the label like

```
[yourLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

in interface builder.
Click on UILabel. and then property tab. Under **View** make sure user **Interaction** is unchecked

[image]

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    //This will ignore all UILabel touch event
    if ([[touch.view class] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) return;

   //do something for touch event for other UIElements




}
```

Comment: are you using interface builder

Comment: where did you put your touchUpInside method? did  you override UILabel and gave it or it is in the super view of UILabel?

Comment: I Have UILabel in UIViewController and created IBOutlet for it.I did not override it

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the current view you are touching is the UILabel need.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if ([[touch.view class] isSubclassOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        if (touch.view == yourLabel) {
            //Dont do anything if this is your label.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check in touchpoints with your label's frame.